# Using the tr command

Tags: shell, command-line, tail, tr

Assume that the file `ft` has 25 lines of text. Explain the command:

```
tail -15 ft | tr "a" "A" > ft
```

and tell me how many lines the file `ft` has after the execution of the command.

I understand that `tail -15 ft` will grab the last 15 lines from the `ft` file and that `tr 'a' 'A'` will change any `a` into `A`.

But I don't understand why `> tr` deletes everything from the file.

Comment: What is this, a homework question that you've partially answered, but where you're stuck on one piece?  If so, (1) good for you for doing your best to do it yourself before asking for help, but (2) provide *context*.  You presented a problem, and then your partial answer, without *explaining* what you were doing.

Comment: See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators? — Warning regarding ‘>’](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126).

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that fist the shell sets up redirections (in this case, `> ft`), and that truncates `ft` and opens it for writing; then it sets up the rest of the pipeline. `tail -15 ft` gets an empty file and gives an empty result, which `tr` handles to replace nothing. `ft` is an empty file as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [standard output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) and not [appending redirected output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) *If you're trying to append the output to your original file, what I don't think so*.

From `man bash`

> **Redirecting Output** If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.
>
> **Appending Redirected Output** Redirection of output in this fashion causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for appending on file descriptor n, or the standard output (file  descrip‐
>          tor 1) if n is not specified.  If the file does not exist it is created.

So, as you're specifying to redirect the output to the same file, this will be truncated and created with the expected output

What I suggest to do is to use `sed` with the `redirection`

```
$ tail -15 ft | sed -e 's|a|A|g' > sed_output
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not using the correct bash notation.

In bash, you have to use '>file' to overwrite a file and '>>file' to append to it.  Instead, use '>>ft'.

Comment: It's a correct statement, but I don't think this answers the question

Comment: Fine, I'll clarify.

Comment: The OP might not want to append to the file. (IMO it looks pretty much like they simply wanted to replace the contents with the pipe processing, but didn't understand why the `> ft` didn't get executed at the end of the pipeline.)

Comment: *facepalm* Then they can just use "cmd | echo >>./file"